# Display an HTML file in a VUE project

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning WHAT, and I have several examples of HTML code.
And they are in .html files.
I need help.
How can I display this html file in a VUE file.

`/DOM/template.html`

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>Usando Vue!</p>
</div>
```

`App.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">

  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    /* HelloWorld */
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't think `id='app'` is available for components as vue already used that id as wrapper for the codes at the index file under `public`

If you wanted to import html as component, like example below:

`<template>`

```html
<html-import></html-import>
```

under `<script>`

```js
import htmlImport from '/src/assets/htmlimport.html'
data(){return{}
},
components:{htmlImport},
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Create `htmlContent.js` file

```
const htmlContent = `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <title>Ashok Parmar</title>
  </html>
`;
export default htmlContent
```

#### Vue.js 3

```
import htmlFileContent from './htmlContent.js';
const htmlFileText = ref('');
htmlFileText.value = htmlFileContent;
```